# ServiceWorker: Browser not detecting new version

Tags: html, caching, service-worker

I'm experimenting with the HTML5 ServiceWorker API based on [this article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/service-worker/introduction/). In the article it is mentioned that

> When the user navigates to your site, the browser tries to redownload
>   the script file that defined the service worker in the background. If
>   there is even a byte's difference in the service worker file compared
>   to what it currently has, it considers it 'new'.

From which I conclude that if I would change *anything* in the worker's script file, it would prompt the browser to define a new version that would kick in when all pages referencing the old version of the worker are terminated.

---

**Edit:** Apparently the browser is caching the `serviceworker.js` file itself, which is why new versions aren't picked up. Could anyone tell me how to avoid caching the worker file? I've looked through the available demo's online (including those on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorker_API/Using_Service_Workers) and [W3C Webmob's GitHub](https://github.com/w3c-webmob/ServiceWorkersDemos))

This is my file structure:

```
|- index.html
|- serviceworker.js // the actual worker
|- serviceworker-cache-polyfill.js
|- serviceworker-registration.js // contains the registration logic for the worker
|- style.css
```

I configured my cache to include following URLs:

- "/style.css"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was not the configuration of the ServiceWorker, but the fact my server cached the file. Can't say I don't feel stupid I didn't checked this earlier.

For future reference, I am using [http-server](https://github.com/indexzero/http-server), it caches by default all files for 1 hour. You can override this by passing in the `c` parameter. To disable caching altogether, pass in `-1`:

```
http-server -c-1
```

**Edit** The following [article](https://www.chromium.org/blink/serviceworker/getting-started) contains a good summary on how to develop with the ServiceWorker:

> In order to guarantee that the latest version of your Service Worker
>   script is being used, follow these instructions:
>
> 1. Configure your local server to serve your Service Worker script as non-cacheable (cache-control: no-cache)
> 2. After you made changes to your service
>      worker script:
>
>    1. close all but one of the tabs pointing to your web application
>    2. hit shift-reload to bypass the service worker as to ensure
>         that the remaining tab isn't under the control of a service worker
>    3. hit
>         reload to let the newer version of the Service Worker control the
>         page.

Answer (score 1):

That would indeed explain the behavior. The update logic does respect the HTTP cache control header but up to 24 hours (to avoid being stuck with a broken SW served with a Cache-control: 1 year header).

Comment: May this occur you could always use a cache buster or rename your serviceworker. This only works if the page that installs the serviceworker is not cached by the broken version.